# Show that $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for $x \geq 0 $ is point wise and/or uniform, or does not converge at all

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for $x \geq 0 $ defined by
$$f_n(x)= \frac{x^n}{x^n +n}$$
is point wise and/or uniform, or does not converge at all

---

Its easy enough to define
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} f_n(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad 0 \leq x \leq1\\
            1 & \quad x > 1
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
therefore its safe to assume that it is not continuous, when graphed , thus it is not uniform, how. would I show that it is point-wise rigorously?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You already computed the pointwise limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} f_n(x)$ for each $x$ and noted that it is not continuous, therefore the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Write $$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{n}{x^n}}$$ and your pointwise limit becomes very easy to prove (indeed for $x>1$, $\frac n{x^n}\to 0$ and for $0\le x\le 1$, $\frac{n}{x^n}\to\infty$)

Comment: My professor did indeed write $f_n(x)$ as you did.However how does it  make it easier to prove. I will update the question with his hints. I'm sorry if I am being a bit slow. I understand how to prove the more simpler proof of point wise but thus one is messing with me @Maximilian Janisch

Comment: @EverOlivares It puts all of the stuff that's changing together. You've almost certainly already proven that $(n/x^n)$ has the limits above for each value of $x$, so the chain & product rules for sequences give you the limit of $f_n(x)$ immediately.